# android studio creates wierd dot file location occasionally

Tags: android, flutter

When creating directory 'auth' in directory 'services', android studio creates a directory called services.auth

I clicked on refactor and added a new file called 'auth' .  i added this file to the services.auth location.  the result was a new directory called services.auth.auth.

I assumed i would get services.auth/auth.

The reason I did this is that i could move my auth files to the new auth folder, create a new services folder and move service directories into services folder.

Comment: `services.auth` means `services` has a single child directory named `auth`. If you add another child directory to `services`, it will show the hierarchy you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

They are directories, but Android Studio just displays them as package names.

If you change the view to "Project files", it will show the directory structure instead:

[image: Project files]

Comment: thank you.  that was the correct fix.  I don't understand why android studio would do that only for the services.auth.  i now have to reformat and move other directories out of auth and into it's 'parent' services.

Comment: It's essentially just showing you the package names that you're actually using when you have "Project" view selected. Most of the time that is fine and reduces clutter, except when you're trying to change/refactor the project structure.